# Localization with Laravel5 without domain.com/language/

Tags: php, laravel, localization, laravel-5

I'm setting up a learning-by-doing project with Laravel and facing localization. I've seen on the forum that there's a language-package available but I think (assume) Laravel provides something I'm looking for, although I don't know where to look yet.

Basically I have a view which renders using blade. Nothing special. I've tried to use `App::setLocale('nl')` to get the translations, which works nice.

Then, after my view got a bit messy I started to put some stuff in several files using `@extends()` and `@section()`, I noticed each file has to call `App::setLocale()` in order to fetch the translations. This seems a bit unhandy...

Is there a way to set the language for the entire life-cycle of a request for all views and subviews? (Without Laravel I would store this using `$_SESSION[]`, `$_COOKIE` or in the database and then setting it in the index.php-file)

I'm not trying to develop something like `www.domain.com/nl/stuff` for the Dutch version and `www.domain.com/en/stuff` for the English version. There's no need for SEO since I'm creating a sort-of web-app.

Any idea where to find this?

P.s. I know I can set the language in `/config/app.php` but I would also like to provide a language-dropdown for users to select their desired language. (Where the number of available languages could grow)

Comment: you can set the locale in 

> app/config/app.php

Comment: I know, but that wasn't what I wanted to do, as I mentioned. Nonetheless thanks for taking time to respond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't set the locale inside the view. You should do it *before* all the views get rendered. For example in a [middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware)

For example something like this:

```
class LangMiddleware {

/**
 * Run the request filter.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Input::has('lang')){
            App::setLocale(Input::get('lang'));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And then register this as global middleware and you can do `?lang=en` on the request to set the locale. This is just an example you can do whatever you want... ;)

Comment: Ah great! I'm still getting familiair with putting everthing outside my view. This works like a charm! I've registered the middleware in the Kernel's middleware so it runs every request. Thanks, +1. Have a nice day sir.